# How can I set Unique Invoices in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

have data which looks like this :

```
                    Sales Invoice #| Invoice Date|Amount|Product 
                      75025134     | 9/20/2019   |220   | A
                      75025134     | 9/20/2019   |220   | A
                      75025135     | 9/20/2019   |222    |B
```

My desired output shall be Product A , Unique Invoice =1, Amount = 220 ,  we shall only charge customer on Unique per invoice.The system however stores Invoices# on basis of order date, ship to data. How can I normalize this in sql.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what results did you get?

Comment: you can look up the concept `distinct`

Comment: Redesign your system to use one row for the invoice and invoice date and charges in an invoice table and the rows for the items on the invoice in a separate table that records invoice, product, ship date and amount.

Comment: Why are there two identical rows in the first place?

Comment: 'The system however stores Invoices# on basis of order date, ship to data' - it's a good idea to present your sample data in a way that is consistent with the question - your sample does not have order date or ship to data. Are you saying that one row is generated when the order is placed and another row generated when it is shipped?

Answer (score 1):

Are you simply looking for `select distinct`?

```
select distinct sales_invoice, invoice_date, amount, product
from t;
```

Comment: Hello, Well I know Distinct function, But how will I define Unique Orders ? eg: Invoice Date| Sales invoice #| Unique Invoice                     09/25/2019 |200|1             09/25/2019| 200|0 ,  How can I define Unique order, I want to define new column saying Unique Order, Henceforth Invoice Date| Sales invoice #| Unique Invoice                     
 09/25/2019 |200|1             09/25/2019| 200|0                                  1

Comment: @S.Y.K.J . . . This answers the question that you have asked in this question.  If you want to define a new column in the data, please ask a new question, with appropriate sample data and desired results.